# How to change a class without re-coding?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am creating a drivers license object in my project, that employees will all have one of their own linked to their unique clock number. I have a separate table in my database for the driving license but in the future more types of vehicles will need to be added, is there anyway to do this without re-coding?
the columns in my database are the same as the attributes for the class below

```
public class LicenseDTO
{
    public int ClockNo { get; set; }
    public bool CBalance { get; set; }
    public bool MR16 { get; set; }
    public bool OrderPicker { get; set; }
    public bool Reach { get; set; }
    public bool Pedestrian { get; set; }
    public bool Lorry { get; set; }
    public bool Sweeper { get; set; }
    public bool Washer { get; set; }
}
```

*EDIT*

I have tried to create this the best I could but I feel like it's really long winded and can be done a more efficient way. Here's an updated version of my code.

```
public class LicenseDTO
{
    public int ClockNo { get; set; }
    public List<Common.VehicleTypeDTO> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleTypeDTO
{
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
    public bool Allowed { get; set; }
}

private void btnClockCardIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Common.LicenseDTO License = new Common.LicenseDTO();
        List<Common.VehicleTypeDTO> Vehicles = new List<Common.VehicleTypeDTO>();
        Common.VehicleTypeDTO CBalance = new Common.VehicleTypeDTO();
        Common.VehicleTypeDTO MR16 = new Common.VehicleTypeDTO();
        License.Vehicles = Vehicles;
        CBalance.VehicleType = "CBalance";
        CBalance.Allowed = true;
        MR16.VehicleType = "MR16";
        MR16.Allowed = false;
        License.Vehicles.Add(CBalance);
        License.Vehicles.Add(MR16);
        foreach (Common.VehicleTypeDTO Vehicle in License.Vehicles)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Vehicle.VehicleType + " " + Vehicle.Allowed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: without re-coding? probably an through xml file but why?

Comment: Basically I am on a years placement, and the last placement student so nobody will be maintaining these apps, got to future proof it

Comment: Rather than having a defined list of 'vehicles' have a collection of vehicles for each license with a type identifier.

Comment: Don't get so wrapped up in attempting to keep your code brief. Verbosity is not a crime. I don't see anything wrong with your edit. It appears to do what you want. If you're desperate then inline your VehicleTypeDTO property settings on creation: `new Common.VehicleTypeDTO() { VehicleType = "CBalance", Allowed = true};`.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to create a table with  the types of vehicles? In the future you can access to your table and insert more types.

```
public class VehicleTypeDTO
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class LicenseDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<VehicleTypeDTO> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create you an example (Console application) https://github.com/parxal/53633241 , And Please Check : Database Diagram.JPG , Database script.sql

Answer (score 0):

You should have made an entity LicenseDTO with the attributes ClockNo and CBalance alongside an array of the type Vehicle. which will be an interface. the interface Vehicle can define any common methods the vehicles have. and all future vehicles will have to implement the interface. that way you dont have to change any code. Your current code cannot be "changed" without editing. You could try to extend your LicenseDTO class with another entityclass which implements the above interface. but there isnt much more you can do without editing.

If you want maintainability use interfaces, repository patterns, abstract classes and dependency injection to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple bit columns in your database to indicate different types of vehicles, have a single `VehicleType` table. Then you can add as many different vehicle types as you like and use the VehicleTypeID to uniquely identify them. You can then add more and more vehicle types to the table without having to write more code.

```
VehicleType
    VehicleTypeID int
    VehicleTypeName varchar(50)

public class LicenseDTO
{
    public int ClockNo { get; set; }
    public int VehicleTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to have multiple types of vehicles against a single ClockNo then use a list of int:

```
public class LicenseDTO
{
    public int ClockNo { get; set; }
    public List<int> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Alternately you could have a reference to the VehicleType objects instead of just the ID's.